# Why does Export not raise an error message?

Tags: export

Why does `Export["str", str, "Table"]` *not* evaluate to an error, where `str` is any expression?

Comment: What happens if you evaluate `Import[ "str", "Table"]` immediately after?

Comment: @Jason B `{{"str"}}` which, to me, is equally weird;

Comment: This seems like expected behavior.  The doc page says "The Wolfram Language automatically transforms arbitrary expressions to a list of lists when exporting to the "Table" format."  - if you need to restrict this to only tabular data you could write a small wrapper function that checks that the input is the right form and then calls `Export`

Comment: I didn't know/haven't read that but that's not the source of my confusion; isn't the first argument to `Export` supposed to be a path/url? here, `"str"` is neither.

Comment: "str" is a perfectly good path relative to the current directory.

Comment: also, the code in my Q, doesn't return `{{"str"}}` but "str" which usually is the path it exported `str` to

Comment: @JohnDoty but that supposed path doesn't exist, right? also, `Export["str\\", str, "Table"]` returns with a `OpenWrite::noopen` message as one would expect

Comment: `Export["str", ... , "Table"]` exports to the file `"str"` (without file extension) in `Directory[]`. So the full file path is `FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "str"}]`. Notice also that a single symbol in the second argument will converted to a string and then written to file. Run `Import["str", "Text"]` in order to see the verbatim file content. Hence, it is `Import` that converts to a table, not export.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher ok, that makes sense

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `Export` converts the arbitrary `expr` to `{{expr}}` **before** it exports it as a table.  `Import` then also returns the data as a table, because that's the format given.

Comment: @JasonB. So I had thought before I executed `Export["str", expr, "Table"]; Import["str", "Text"]` (version 11.3 on macOS),

Comment: But that's what you would expect a single-item CSV or TSV file to look like - just one entry

Comment: @JasonB. "Export converts the arbitrary expr to {{expr}} before it exports it as a table. " This is false. `ExportString["FOO", "Table"]` gives just `FOO` and when Import sees only one element in the file, it still imports as a 2d list.

Comment: @GenericAccountName in what way is it false?  `ExportString["FOO", "Table"]` produces the same output as the documented syntax `ExportString[{{"FOO"}}, "Table"]`.  As to whether the underlying functions actually **do** convert it to a nested list is an implementation detail and therefore beside the point.  The point is that `Export` is documented to treat a non-array input by first converting it to an array and then exporting as usual, and the behavior here is consistent with that.

Comment: @JasonB. the output is still just "FOO". This is really just semantics.